# Virtual Environment (or alternative) within a pip-installed package

Tags: python, pip, dependency-management, python-venv

I am a developer for a set of python apps that are used internally by a company. These apps are stored on private git repos that act as package repos (like PyPI).The apps are installed on office computers using pip:

`pip install git+http://path-to-app1`

Once this command is run, the app is ready to use. All the end user needs to do is run an .exe that is included inside the package.

Many of the apps have the same dependencies, but sometimes require different versions of the same package. My question is, is there a way to set up the python projects so that when these apps are pip-installed, each app has it's own copy of it's dependent packages?

For example, if app1 requires package A version 1.0., and app2 requires package A version 2.0, I could pip install both app1 and app2 globally, and each would have it's own copy of package A in its respectively appropriate version stored somewhere. Like a virtual environment, but for an installed package.

We use both python 2 and 3, so a solution in either language would be helpful.

Comment: It sounds like you should take a look at [pipx](https://github.com/pypa/pipx), which solves exactly this problem.

Comment: Thank you, this looks like what I was looking for.